# RESTEasy application works in tomcat 8.5 but not in tomcat 10.1

Tags: tomcat, server, resteasy

I follow RESTEasy tutorial from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLi1-PNwM7U). I did everything same. The sample project works with Tomcat v8.5 but it does not work with Tomcat v10.1 in Eclipse IDE. There is no spesific error so I cannot understand why is that ? When I make a request to an api I get 404 error with this description : `The requested resource [/resteasy-helloworld-example/restapi/hello] is not available`.

The source code :

HelloWorld.java

```
package org.utarid.resteasytutorial.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class HelloWorld {
    private String message;

    public HelloWorld(String message) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

HelloWorldResource.java

```
package org.test.resteasytutorial.resource;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.test.resteasytutorial.model.HelloWorld;

@Path("hello")
public class HelloWorldResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response helloWorld()
    {
        HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld("hello world");
        return Response.ok(helloWorld).build();
    }
}
```

RestEasyServices.java

```
package org.test.resteasytutorial.resource;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/restapi")
public class RestEasyServices extends Application {
    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

    public RestEasyServices() {
        this.singletons.add(new HelloWorldResource());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-helloworld-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>resteasy-helloworld-example Maven Webapp</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <resteasy.version>3.15.6.Final</resteasy.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Set up RESTEasy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--  RESTEasy Client Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>resteasy-helloworld-example</finalName>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven
            defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see
                http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

I tried same code with Tomcat 10.1 without changing anything. But it does not work and there is not error. It says . `The requested resource [/resteasy-helloworld-example/restapi/hello] is not available`. But I can reach same api with Tomcat 8.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Now the code works with Tomcat 10.1 but does not work with Tomcat 8.5. First I added JakartaEE dependency to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>10.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then I changed all javax.* imports to jakarta.*. I removed `@XmlRootElement` from HelloWorld.java and added `jackson` dependency for json.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Also I updated all dependencies. Now updated version of pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Your question didn't mention any `javax.*` imports. Your tutorial link also appears broken. How is adding JakartaEE APIs the right solution to work with Tomcat 10.1 when you didn't need to add JavaEE APIs to work with Tomcat 8.5?

Comment: I have updated the link. sorry for that. Also you can see javax.* imports in HelloWorld.java and HelloWorldResource.java in the question. I looked the tomcat website and it says "This release implements specifications that are part of the Jakarta EE 10 platform." for Tomcat 10. That's why I changed javax to jakarta. New code does not work with Tomcat 8.5 now.